# How to wait for multiple threads to finish without blocking ui in android?

Tags: android

I am executing tasks parallelly on threads using threadPoolExecuter and i want to wait for all the tasks to complete without blocking the main ui. I don't want to use async task here. and methods like service.awaitTermination() is blocking the main ui.I have checked similar questions but didn't find answer to my particular problem. I am using a for loop to pass runnables to threads like this :

```
for (ApplicationInfo info : applicationInfoList) {
        service.execute(new MyTask(info));
    }
```

MyTask() function execute the same opertaion for all the ApplicationInfo type objects here.
Please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can see you are using java, so probably you aren't allowed for some reason to use coroutines. With coroutines, it would be easier to achieve such a result.
Consider using them, especially have a look at their way to solve your [problem](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html).

What I would use in your case is - [CountDownLatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch).

Your code will look similar to this one:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(applicationInfoList.size);
            for (ApplicationInfo info : applicationInfoList) {
                service.execute(new MyTask(info, latch));
            }
            latch.await();
```

`MyTask` under the hood should call `latch.countDown()` when your work is done.

`latch.await()` throws `InterruptedException` so it should be handled.

**Note:** Anyway, it blocks the thread you are currently on.
The easiest way would be to migrate this logic to Runnable and provide a callback:

```
class YourButchTask implements Runnable {
            
            private WorkDoneCallback callback;

            public YourButchTask(WorkDoneCallback callback) {
                this.callback = callback;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(applicationInfoList.size);
                for (ApplicationInfo info : applicationInfoList) {
                    service.execute(new MyTask(info, latch));
                }
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //handle it
                }
                callback.workWasDone();
            }
        }
```

Afterward, you can submit your task to your `service`.
**Note**: your callback will be invoked from the executor thread, so you aren't allowed to access UI from it.

Here is a nice and simple [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-wait-for-threads#:%7E:text=When%20using%20an%20Executor%2C%20we,using%20the%20awaitTermination()%20method.), hopefully, that will help.

**Update:**

To be clear - `Callback` is your custom interface that will notify you when the work is done. Go ahead and use SAM, example:

```
interface WorkDoneCallback{
    void workWasDone();
}
```

**P.S.** To redirect calls on main thread just use `Handler` with `mainLooper` under the hood, or `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: what to do if i want to access ui from callback ? is it runOnui method that i should use ??
Basically i am sending a list to my recyclerview that i computed in MyTask().